# Are nilpotent Lie groups unimodular?

Tags: functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, banach-algebras, locally-compact-groups

The continuous homomorphism $\Delta:G \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{\times}_+$ is defined by
\begin{equation*}
\int_G f(xy)dx = \Delta(y)\int_Gf(x)dx
\end{equation*}
where $dx$ is a left Haar measure on $G$. $G$ is called unimodular if and only if $\Delta(y) = 1$.

Are nilpotent Lie groups unimodular?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, locally compact nilpotent groups are unimodular.

In fact, a locally compact group $G$ is unimodular if and only if $G/Z(G)$ is unimodular where $Z(G)$ is the center of $G$ -- see L. Nachbin, *The Haar integral*, corollary to Proposition 25, page 92. Abelian groups are unimodular and a simple induction on the length of the central series now shows that $n$-step nilpotent groups are unimodular.

Solvable groups are not unimodular in general, as the standard example of the $(ax + b)$-group shows.

Comment: hi @Martin, could you give me a reference that has the  (ax+b) -group? (I'm trying to find an explicit example of a solvable connected lie groups that are not unimodular)