# Trace of the adjoint representation

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite dimensional Lie algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathrm{ad}$ be its adjoint representation. Is it true that $\mathrm{tr}(\mathrm{ad}(x)) = 0$ for any $x \in \mathfrak{g}$? Written in terms of a set of structure constants $c_{ij}^k$, it is equivalent to prove
$$
\sum_{s} c_{is}^{s} = 0
$$
for any $i$.

When $\mathfrak{g}$ is a matrix Lie algebra, we can prove this result by direct computation. Since any finite dimensional Lie algebra can be realized as a matrix Lie algebra, I guess this result is true for any finite dimensional Lie algebra. But if it is true, then it imposes a new constraint on structure constants, what is wrong?

Comment: Have you checked your claim on the two-dimensional nonabelian Lie algebra?

Comment: As a general strategy, if I see something claimed for *all* (finite-dim.) Lie algebras, and I don't see a full proof or counterexample right away, I try to check in my head if I see it, in this order : 1) for abelian Lie algebras 2) for semisimple Lie algebras 3) for the two-dimensional nonabelian LA 4) for LAs consisting of strictly upper triangular matrices 5) for LAs consisting of upper triangular matrices 6) for all solvable LAs 7) for *all* (finite-dim.) Lie algebras. That often saves me wasted work on a proof when I notice counterexamples in an early step. Like here, in step 3.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful suggestion! I noticed that I made a wrong argument when I transit from the general linear Lie algebra to a matrix Lie algebra.

Comment: Yes, the claim is true for any *full* matrix Lie algebra $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ (and it's nice to see why), but that does not imply it for just any LA consisting of matrices.

Answer (score 2):

A Lie algebra $L$ is called *unimodular* if ${\rm tr}({\rm ad}(x))=0$ for all $x\in L$. This comes from *unimodular Lie groups*, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323017/are-nilpotent-lie-groups-unimodular). Clearly nilpotent and semisimple Lie algebras are unimodular. On the other hand, the affine Lie algebra $\mathfrak{aff}(K^n)$ is not unimodular, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/731337/intuition-behind-the-failure-of-unimodularity). For $n=1$ the affine Lie algebra is the $2$-dimensional nonabelian Lie algebra.

Unimodularity is important for the *Poincare duality* concerning Lie algebra homology and cohomology. See also [this MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/184590/poincar%C3%A9-duality-for-cohomology-of-lie-algebras) for more on it.

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful answer! This geometric interpretation is interesting for me. By the way, in the first line I guess you mean tr(ad(x))=0

Comment: Thank you, yes, typo corrected.

Comment: How do you show semisimple Lie algebras are unimodular? Does it involve $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-representations?

Comment: @ArB There are several ways to show this. Reductive groups and hence reductive Lie algebras are unimodular, see [this MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/267592/simple-proof-that-a-reductive-group-is-unimodular). On the level of (semisimple) Lie algebras, since we have $L=[L,L]$, and ${\rm ad} ([x,y])=[{\rm ad}(x),{\rm ad}(y))]$ we have ${\rm tr(ad (}x))=0$ for all $x\in L$.